Handle error in instruction
I have an instruction as below. When an error occurs in the instruction, I want to display the error on the user interface
pub fn claim_token(ctx: Context<Claim>, end_time: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let sleeper_account = &mut ctx.accounts.sleeper_account;
    sleeper_account.end_time = end_time;

    let start_time = sleeper_account.start_time;

    let time_difference = end_time.saturating_sub(start_time);

    if time_difference < MIN_TIME {
        return err!(ClaimError::NotEnoughTime);
    }

    if time_difference > MAX_TIME {
        sleeper_account.start_time = 0;
        return err!(ClaimError::OutTime);
    }

    //     random 5 - 25 sl token
    let amount: u64 = random_token(5, 25);

    //     mint token
    let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
        mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().clone(),
        to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info().clone(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
    };

    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
    token_interface::mint_to(cpi_context, amount * 1000000)?;

    sleeper_account.start_time = 0;

    msg!("Great, you have a good night sleep ");

    Ok(())
}

transaction
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3Z4VqkBNknAba42iHeH1Z7t8oT88uoXxewCq16fxSufhk8bDaSrfbnaqv4fq2mgidfKWAUdMbx2M5tJ9FDh1B8ik?cluster=devnet
